# Find records with overlapping date range in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_wer(
  id_customer NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(10),
  surname VARCHAR2(20),
  date_from DATE,
  date_to DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT customer_wer_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_customer, data_from));

INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-JAN-00', '31-MAR-00');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-APR-00', '30-JUN-00');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '15-JUN-00', '30-SEP-00');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-OCT-00', '31-DEC-00');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-JAN-01', '31-MAR-01');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-APR-01', '30-JUN-01');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-JUL-01', '5-OCT-01');
INSERT INTO customer_wer VALUES (4, 'Karolina', 'Komuda', '01-OCT-01', '31-DEC-01');
```

I need a `SELECT` query to find the records with overlapping dates. It means that in the example above, I should have four records in result

```
number 
2
3
7
8
```

Thank you in advance.
I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: As @RahulTripathi suggests, you'll have to tell us what DB you are using and probably also the version. This is something for which Windowing Functions or Temporal tables are highly useful, but not all DB's support those.

Comment: corrected spelling and expanded title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from t t1
join t t2 on (t1.datefrom > t2.datefrom and t1.datefrom < t2.dateto)
          or (t1.dateto > t2.datefrom and t1.dateto < t2.dateto)
```

Thank You for this example. After modification it is working:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_wer k
JOIN customer_wer w
ON k.id_customer = w.id_customer
WHERE (k.date_from > w.date_to AND k.date_from < w.date_to)
OR (k.date_to > w.date_from AND k.date_to < w.date_to);
```

Comment: Does not cover the occurrence of date range within the other date range.

Answer (score 7):

the earlier answer does not account for situations where t2 is entirely within t1

```
select * from t t1
join t t2 on (t1.datefrom > t2.datefrom and t1.datefrom < t2.dateto  )
          or (t1.dateto   > t2.datefrom and t1.dateto   < t2.dateto  )
          or (t1.dateto   > t2.dateto   and t1.datefrom < t2.datefrom)
```

Comment: You may want to include the date (=>, <=)

Comment: also, if you use == then you have to distinguish between 2 rows
 (t1.id != t2.id)

Comment: 6 years later, thanks a lot! I was so stuck trying to do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` and `WHERE EXISTS` and was losing hope I'll ever figure it out. Your post immediately clicked and I had a working query 10 minutes later. May you have good fortune.

Answer (score 1):

If each beginning date is less than or equal to the other record's ending date, then it will be within the range.

If starting date 1 is less than ending date 2 AND starting date 2 is less than ending date 1.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM t t1
    JOIN t t2 ON (t1.datefrom <= t2.dateto)
              AND (t2.datefrom <= t1.dateto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by @Ben ... but check for overlapping == days as well with a check on id to ensure it is unique.

```
select * from seasons t1
join seasons t2 on (t1.season_open  >= t2.season_open  and t1.season_open  <= t2.season_close and t1.id != t2.id)
                or (t1.season_close >= t2.season_open  and t1.season_close <= t2.season_close and t1.id != t2.id)
                or (t1.season_close >= t2.season_close and t1.season_open  <= t2.season_open  and t1.id != t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation with much data in a table better performance was reached in a such way:

```
select *
from (
select id_customer,
       name,
       surname,
       date_from,
       date_to,
       lead(id_customer) over (partition by id_customer order by date_from) id_customer1,
       lead(name)        over (partition by id_customer order by date_from) name1,
       lead(surname)     over (partition by id_customer order by date_from) surname1,
       lead(date_from)   over (partition by id_customer order by date_from) date_from1,
       lead(date_to)     over (partition by id_customer order by date_from) date_to1
 from customer_wer)
where date_from1 <= date_to
```