# how to join tables not according to equality between two fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with a query in SQL oracle and I will be glad to hear if someone here can help me.
so, I have two tables.
One contains start time and end time of something (mostly long times) , and the second contains also start time and end time of something else (mostly short times). I want to join the second table to the first in a way that rows from the second table will be joined to the first when the time in the second are contained in the first.
i will give an example:

first table:

```
name start end
---- ----- -----
a    10:00 12:00
b    16:00 18:00
```

second table:

```
name start end
---- ----- -----
c    11:30 11:45
d    16:15 17:45
```

so, the required table will join the second row in the second table to the second in the first, and similarly the first rows in the tables.

thanks!

Comment: Do your second table has ranges which overlaps two ranges of the first table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find records with overlapping date range in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943714/find-records-with-overlapping-date-range-in-sql)

Comment: What is your expected result? Rows from first table? rows from second table? which columns?

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
select t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.start<=t2.start and t1.end>=t2.end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression in 'ON' clause in your join.

... ON (table1.start <= table2.start AND table1.end >= table2.end) .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your time intervals in table1 don't overlap this would do,

```
Select *
From Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b 
on b.start between a.start and a.end
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, the range of the rows in the second table, have to be entirely included:

```
      SELECT *
        FROM Table_A A
  INNER JOIN Table_B B
          ON B.start BETWEEN A.start AND a.end
         AND B.end   BETWEEN A.start AND a.end
```